# python algorithm for solving systems of equations without

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I need algorithm, that solve systems like this:

Example 1:

```
5x - 6y = 0                      <--- line
(10- x)**2 + (10- y)**2 = 2      <--- circle
```

Solution:

```
find y:          
(10- 6/5*y)**2 + (10- y)**2 = 2   
100 - 24y + 1.44y**2 + 100 - 20y + y**2 = 2  
2.44y**2 - 44y + 198 = 0
D = b**2 - 4ac
D = 44*44 - 4*2.44*198 = 3.52
y[1,2] = (-b+-sqrt(D))/2a
y[1,2] = (44+-1.8761)/4.88 = 9.4008 , 8.6319

find x:
(10- x)**2 + (10- 5/6y)**2 = 2   
100 - 20x + y**2 + 100 - 5/6*20y + (5/6*y)**2 = 2  
1.6944x**2 - 36.6666x + 198 = 0
D = b**2 - 4ac
D = 36.6666*36.6666 - 4*1.6944*198 = 2.4747
x[1,2] = (-b+-sqrt(D))/2a
x[1,2] = (36.6666+-1.5731)/3.3888 = 11.2841 , 10.3557
```

my skills are not enough to write this algorithm please help

and another algorithm that solve this system.

```
5x - 6y = 0                    <--- line
|-10 - x| + |-10 - y| = 2      <--- rhomb
```

as answer here i need two x and two y.

Comment: stackover flow is not somewhere to just have someone solve and complete your homework or assignement. please show some effort, attempt the problem, share your code, let us know any errors etc

Comment: What are *"equations without"* (in your subject)?

Comment: Your question is not fit for stack overflow. You should tell us what you have done, what error you are facing, what kind of help do you need. We can not just write the code in star overflow. In stack overflow we are supposed to ask questions and put effort before you ask them. Please try to solve this before you ask for help. One question you could ask is if there is a package or module for the computer to calculate the math equation with steps. But this question just asks for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sympy, Python's symbolic math library.

## Solutions for fixed parameters

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)
eq1 = Eq(5 * x - 6 * y, 0)
eq2 = Eq((10 - x) ** 2 + (10 - y) ** 2, 2)
solutions = solve([eq1, eq2], (x, y))
print(solutions)
for x, y in solutions:
    print(f'{x.evalf()}, {y.evalf()}')
```

This leads to two solutions:

```py
[(660/61 - 6*sqrt(22)/61,   550/61 - 5*sqrt(22)/61),
 (6*sqrt(22)/61 + 660/61, 5*sqrt(22)/61 + 550/61)]

10.3583197613288, 8.63193313444070
11.2810245009662, 9.40085375080520
```

The other equations work very similar:

```py
eq1 = Eq(5 * x - 6 * y, 0)
eq2 = Eq(Abs(-10 - x) + Abs(-10 - y), 2)
```

leading to :

```py
[(-12, -10),
 (-108/11, -90/11)]

-12.0000000000000, -10.0000000000000
-9.81818181818182, -8.18181818181818
```

## Dealing with arbitrary parameters

For your new question, how to deal with arbitrary parameters, sympy can help to find formulas, at least when the structure of the equations is fixed:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, Abs, solve

x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)
a, b, xc, yc = symbols('a b xc yc', real=True)
r = symbols('r', real=True, positive=True)
eq1 = Eq(a * x - b * y, 0)
eq2 = Eq((xc - x) ** 2 + (yc - y) ** 2, r ** 2)
solutions = solve([eq1, eq2], (x, y))
```

Studying the generated solutions, some complicated expressions are repeated.  Those could be substituted by auxiliary variables. Note that this step isn't necessary, but helps a lot in making sense of the solutions. Also note that substitution in sympy often only considers quite literal replacements. That's by the introduction of `c` below is done in two steps:

```py
c, d = symbols('c d', real=True)
for xi, yi in solutions:
    print(xi.subs(a ** 2 + b ** 2, c)
          .subs(r ** 2 * a ** 2 + r ** 2 * b ** 2, c * r ** 2)
          .subs(-a ** 2 * xc ** 2 + 2 * a * b * xc * yc - b ** 2 * yc ** 2 + c * r ** 2, d)
          .simplify())
    print(yi.subs(a ** 2 + b ** 2, c)
          .subs(r ** 2 * a ** 2 + r ** 2 * b ** 2, c * r ** 2)
          .subs(-a ** 2 * xc ** 2 + 2 * a * b * xc * yc - b ** 2 * yc ** 2 + c * r ** 2, d)
          .simplify())
```

Which gives the formulas:

```py
x1 = b*(a*yc + b*xc - sqrt(d))/c
y1 = a*(a*yc + b*xc - sqrt(d))/c
x2 = b*(a*yc + b*xc + sqrt(d))/c
y2 = a*(a*yc + b*xc + sqrt(d))/c
```

These formulas then can be converted to regular Python code without the need of sympy. That code will only work for an arbitrary line and circle. Some tests need to be added around, such as `c == 0` (meaning the line is just a dot), and `d` either be zero, positive or negative.

The stand-alone code could look like:

```py
import math

def give_solutions(a, b, xc, yc, r):
    # intersection between a line a*x-b*y==0 and a circle with center (xc, yc) and radius r
    c =a ** 2 + b ** 2
    if c == 0:
        print("degenerate line equation given")
    else:
        d = -a**2 * xc**2 + 2*a*b * xc*yc - b**2 * yc**2 + c * r**2
        if d < 0:
            print("no solutions")
        elif d == 0:
            print("1 solution:")
            print(f"  x1 = {b*(a*yc + b*xc)/c}")
            print(f"  y1 = {a*(a*yc + b*xc)/c}")
        else: # d > 0
            print("2 solutions:")
            sqrt_d = math.sqrt(d)
            print(f"  x1 = {b*(a*yc + b*xc - sqrt_d)/c}")
            print(f"  y1 = {a*(a*yc + b*xc - sqrt_d)/c}")
            print(f"  x2 = {b*(a*yc + b*xc + sqrt_d)/c}")
            print(f"  y2 = {a*(a*yc + b*xc + sqrt_d)/c}")
```

For the rhombus, sympy doesn't seem to be able to work well with `abs` in the equations. However, you could use equations for the 4 sides, and test whether the obtained intersections are inside the range of the rhombus. (The four sides would be obtained by replacing `abs` with either `+` or `-`, giving four combinations.)

Working this out further, is far beyond the reach of a typical stackoverflow answer, especially as you seem to ask for an even more general solution.

Comment: I need algorythm without another libraries

Comment: You'll end up implementing a part of sympy yourself.  You'll also need to tackle each type of system of equations separately.   Sympy still can be used to work out the formulas.